# Python Expression Tree only able to contain three values

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, expression-trees, postfix-mta, prefix

For the following code, a prefix expression is turned into an expression tree in python.

I am trying to turn a prefix expression into an inflix expression by traversing the expression tree from left to right. The code works if there are only three values in the expression (i.e. "+ 1 2"). But the output list won't contain anymore than three items.

Any hint would be highly appreciated!

```
ops = ['+','-','*','/']

class BinaryTreeNode:
    #def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

class BinarySearchTree:
    
    def __init__(self):
       self.root = None
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)    
    
    def add(self,value):
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = BinaryTreeNode(value)
            
        else:
            #pointer set at root if root not empty
            ptr = self.root
            while True:
               
                if value in ops:
                    ptr = self.root
                    #if left of pointer is empty, add new Node
                    if ptr.left is None:
                        ptr.left = BinaryTreeNode(value)
                        break
                        #set pointer to new Node
                        ptr = ptr.left
                        
                        
                    #left of pointer is not empty, add right node
                    else:
                        # return pointer to root
                        #ptr = self.root
                        ptr.right = BinaryTreeNode(value)
                        break
                        # reset pointer to new Node
                        ptr = ptr.right                        
                
                #if value not in ops
                else:
                    if ptr.left is None:
                        ptr.left = BinaryTreeNode(value)
                        ptr = ptr.left
                        break
                    
                    else:
                        ptr.right = BinaryTreeNode(value)
                        ptr = ptr.right
                        break
                

    def in_order(self):
        def traverse(node):
            if node.left is not None:
                yield from traverse(node.left)
            yield node.value
           
            
            if node.right is not None:
                yield from traverse(node.right)

            
            
        return traverse(self.root)

exp = "+ 1 2"

split = exp.split()

bst = BinarySearchTree()

for i in split:
    bst.add(i)

print(list(bst.in_order()))
```

input: `"+ 1 2"`
output: `[1, +, 2]`

> good

input: `"+ / 1 2 * 3 4"`
output: `[/, +, 4]`

> what happened?? :-(

Thanks for your time!!

Comment: what `+ / 1 2 * 3 4` need to return?

Comment: If root node has already a left and right branch and an operator is added, the right branch is overwritten. Similar for operands.

Comment: I see. How would I be able to move the pointers along instead of overwriting the branches? I am not sure how pointers work in Python.